# How do I disable Cucumbertests for some builds while enabling some tagged tests in other builds

Tags: spring-boot, tags, cucumber, junit5

I have a Cucumber (version 7.11.1), Spring-boot (2.6.4), junit5 (5.9.2) setup. Using tags I have been able to split builds into no-cucumbertests and tagged tests, enabling me to build the specified from the commandline using Maven.

Before I upgraded to the versions mentioned here, I was able to do a clean "mvn clean install test" and not trigger the cucumbertests. I did that by calling my Suite-class "RunCucumber.java" ( and not "RunCucumberSuite.java" or "RunCucumberSuite.java" , i.e. disregarding namingconventions.)

To build/run a particular cucumber-suite I would do a 'mvn clean install verify -Dtest=RunCucumber -Dgroups="web" ' - to run the suite tagged with "@web".

Except for extracting all Cucumber-related code to a separate project, is there another way to configure default run-no-cucumbertests, i.e. when doing "mvn clean install test", run no cucumbertests?

I know there are some issues regarding Junit5 and cucumberconfiguration, but I have not been able to use tags as described elsewhere.
My RunCucumber-class:

```
@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
@ConfigurationParameters({
    @ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.petshop.store.cucumber.steps"),
    @ConfigurationParameter(key = FILTER_TAGS_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "!@web"),
})
@ExcludeTags("web")
public class RunCucumber {
}
```

The ExcludeTags and FILTER_TAGS_PROPERTY_NAME have no effect...

My Spring Context Initializer-class looks like this:

```
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes = {MyApplication.class,  SenderConfig.class})
public class CucumberTestBase {

@BeforeAll
    public static void setUpClass() {
        // Dummy method so cucumber will recognize this class as glue
        // and use its context configuration.
        LOG.info("Spring boot initialized");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what your problem is. You wrote about your setup and what you want but you left out your maven configuration. You also talk only a little about the actions you took and almost nothing about what happened when you did.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for some guidance